# How to get range from 0 - 1 based on two number range

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, when I am scrolling, I would like to get 0 - 1 when the scroll.x number is from 300 - 400.

So 300 would be 0, then 400 would be 1, and in between would be 0.1, 0.2.
I am attempting to try in the meantime and will post my attempt as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you'll just want a simple remapping function.

```
const remap = (
  value,
  sourceMin,
  sourceMax,
  destMin = 0,
  destMax = 1,
) =>
  destMin +
  ((value - sourceMin) / (sourceMax - sourceMin)) *
    (destMax - destMin);

console.log(remap(300, 300, 400));
console.log(remap(400, 300, 400));
console.log(remap(350, 300, 400));
```

outputs

```
0
1
0.5
```

Note that this function does *not* clamp the output values to the range you specify; if you specify out-of-range inputs, you'll get out-of-range outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract the start value and divide by 100 (the delta of the two values) for getting a value between zero and one.

```js
function f(x) {
    return (x - 300) / 100;
}

console.log(f(300)); // 0
console.log(f(350)); // 0.5
console.log(f(400)); // 1
```