# PYTHON : Convert between 0-> 500 and x -> y

Tags: python

i'm trying to convert a number x between [0;500] into [x;y] in python.

Thanks, Sydney.

Comment: you mean doing y x - 250? Have you read a tutorial on Python?

Comment: Yes i did, of course, but here, if think my question looks bad.... Maybe i should ask to convert "a number between [0;500]  into [x ; y ]  in python."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you need a remap function (I've answered this in JavaScript [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593481/51685)).

```
def remap(
    value,
    source_min,
    source_max,
    dest_min=0,
    dest_max=1,
):
    return dest_min + (
        (value - source_min)
        / (source_max - source_min)
    ) * (dest_max - dest_min)
```

Now, for instance to map the value 250 from between 0 to 500 to the range 0 to 1,

```
>>> remap(250, 0, 500, 0, 1)
0.5
```

I hope I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Please accept and upvote the answer if/when you can.

Comment: I will, trust me ;)